# How to find logic that creates a record

Tags: apex, trigger, metadata, create-records

I have duplicate records being created randomly in my org.  Is there a way to trace down where all logic is occurring that is creating these records?  Something like "Where used" but at the object create level not field level.

Thanks!

Comment: If you know the action that causes this than you can use the debug logs to tell you more.

Comment: Do you know when it's happennig?

Comment: No I don't know when it is happening.  I have the created date but that doesn't really tell me what is triggering it.  And as far as knowing the action causing it, if I knew that i wouldn't need to ask this question.

Comment: What kind of records are they? How often does this happen? Why doesn't the creation date tell you which debug log you need to check what is happening? (Btw, if you don't @ people in a reply they won't be notified of your response.)

Comment: Few checks, like check for the triggers, process builder and flow related to that object directly. Long shot just to know where this obj is referred, You can either try renaming that Object api(so it lists down all the apex classes/code where it is mentioned or in Search in files at Dev console, with those class names we can guess where it could have been referred to insert record.